# how can i plot series first bar's close price of super trend (long/short)?

Tags: pine-script

how can i plot series first bar's close price of super trend (long/short) ?
//@version=5
indicator("Supertrend", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

```
atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green,      style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red,     style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var float first_close = 0.
if barstate.isfirst
    first_close := supertrend
```

Comment: 1st many thanks to, but if you have time to to write the ( plot Line ) too it would be good cause i'm noob

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the close price whenever the direction changes into a variable and then you can plot that variable. Example below

```
//@version=5 
indicator("Supertrend", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green,      style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red,     style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)
var firstbarsclose=close
if direction<0 and direction[1]>0
    firstbarsclose:=close
if direction>0 and direction[1]<0
    firstbarsclose:=close
plot(firstbarsclose,style=plot.style_stepline)
```

Comment: it works well, many thanks mr.rohit Agarwal